# Anyone knows what is a driver implementation in Harmony?

Tags: pic, timer, microchip, mplab, mplab-harmony

When configuring a `Timer Driver` implementation the option for Dynamic and Static appears.

Anyone knows, what does these 2 types mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic drivers in Harmony ask for which peripheral you want to talk to as an argument.
Static drivers have the hardware instance numbers hard coded so don't require an argument.

Have a look for details [here](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m988778.aspx)